# Thresholds are passing but their values are zero

Tags: threshold, k6

I am running a K6 script only for 1 VU on my local. However, "Create" threshold  is displayed zero despite it passes. I wrote it in other way like "http_req_duration{name:${}/cases,method:PUT}": ["max < 100"] but nothing changed.

When I sent the results cloud, timings for "Cancel" request is displayed with this tag but for other one, it is displayed with its complete endpoint.

```js
export const options = {
    scenarios: {
        ListIncidents: {
        executor: "per-vu-iterations",
        vus: 1,
        iterations: 1,
        maxDuration: "40s",
        gracefulStop: "50s",
        },
    },
    thresholds: {
    "http_req_duration{name:Create}": ["p(95) < 300", "p(99) < 400"],
    "http_req_duration{name:Cancel}": ["p(95) < 300", "p(99) < 400"],
   },
};

const URL = "URL";
const URL_2 = "URL_2";

export default function () {
    
    const access_token = Login();

    const headers = {
        //header for requests
        Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    //create 
    let res = http.put(
        `${URL_2}/cases`,
        "{}",
        { headers: headers },
        { tags: { name: "Create" } }
    );
    
    //Cancel 
    mainserverLogin();

    //cancel endpoint
    const cancel = http.post(`${URL}/api/cases/${res.body}/cancel`, "cancelled", {
        tags: { name: "Cancel" },
    });
}

export function handleSummary(data) {
    return {
        stdout: textSummary(data, { indent: "", enableColors: true }),
    };
}
```

[Local Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS1J1.png)

[Cloud Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h974K.png)

(I had to change endpoints because of privacy)

I increased graceful stop time, wrote endpoints in different ways, used different endpoints but these did not solve.

Comment: Get rid of the space after the name in the threshold definition, just to be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `http.put` code sends the headers and tags as two different arguments

```js
let res = http.put(
    `${URL_2}/cases`, // 1st
    "{}",             // 2nd
    { headers: headers },  // 3rd
    { tags: { name: "Create" } } //4th
);
```

the 3rd argument of `http.put` (and most other `http.*` functions is an object with multiple fields. Two of which are `headers` and `tags`.

In your case you set the headers but then send a forth argument `http.put` never looks at. So that it never tags the request correctly to begin with.

The correct code is

```js
let res = http.put(
    `${URL_2}/cases`,
    "{}",
    { 
     headers: headers,
     tags: { name: "Create" },
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks, it fixed the problem with the tags but if I use this threshold for ex:
'http_req_duration{name:${}/cases,method:PUT}': [ 'max < 100' ],

for this http method:
let res = http.put(`${URL}/cases`, "{}", {headers: headers})

it still shows 0 even it passes,

Comment: I suspect that your "name" matching is just not correct.

Comment: You can use `-o json` or `-o csv` to get the exact samples being sent and that will let you see what the value for `name` should be.

Comment: Name is URL/cases in csv file like in http request and http_req_duration is not 0 but in terminal, it still shows 0.